# How to download cron log in CPanel?

Tags: logging, ftp, server, cron, cpanel

I can't view `/var` folder using FTP in CPanel because of permission problem, but there are a lot of important logs there. One of the are cron log `/var/log/cron`. How can I download that file?

If I view it using `cat` command, I can only see a little of it. I need to review all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Liquidweb customer service, my server provider, and got the answer.

You can download it by logging in through FTP using the `root` account. It's not accessible for another user besides `root`.